# Get link for feed of specific post type AND taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, feed

I am able to get a specific post type with `http://www.mywebsite.com/feed/?post_type=post-slug&topic=accountable-care-organizations`, but when I try `http://www.mywebsite.com/feed/?post_type=post-slug&topic=term-slug` (topic being slug of taxonomy), the results do not change. Is it possible to generate a feed with multiple parameters like this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this does work as intended, I just got the taxonomy slug wrong. Oh well, hope this helps someone in the future.